# React Native app - NativeBase DeckSwiper not re rendering immediately when dataSource changes

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using Picker and DeckSwiper from NativeBase, when I select a different topic from the Picker menu, it updates the state that is read by dataSource on the DeckSwiper component, which should re render to show the new content.  It currently only re renders if the first card is swiped.  How can I get it re render as soon as the state has changed?  [Here](https://giphy.com/gifs/26Ff8f8l7cU4wrXe8) is a GIF to show how it's currently working.

Here is the code

```
const Item = Picker.Item;

const topics = [
  { label: "topic 1", value: "1" },
  { label: "topic 2", value: "2" },
  { label: "topic 3", value: "3" }
];

const cards = [
  { text: "Card A", topicId: "1", name: "One" },
  { text: "Card B", topicId: "2", name: "Two" },
  { text: "Card C", topicId: "3", name: "Three" },
  { text: "Card D", topicId: "1", name: "Four" },
  { text: "Card E", topicId: "2", name: "Five" },
  { text: "Card F", topicId: "3", name: "Six" }
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: "1",
      topics: topics,
      cards: cards
    };
  }
  onValueChange(value: string) {
    this.setState({
      selected: value,
      cards: cards.filter(item => item.topicId === value)
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <Form>
            <Picker
              iosHeader="Select one"
              mode="dropdown"
              selectedValue={this.state.selected}
              onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
            >
              {this.state.topics.map((topic, i) => {
                return <Item label={topic.label} value={topic.value} key={i} />;
              })}
            </Picker>
          </Form>
          <View>
            <DeckSwiper
              ref={c => (this._deckSwiper = c)}
              dataSource={this.state.cards}
              renderItem={item => (
                <Card style={{ elevation: 3 }}>
                  <CardItem>
                    <Left>
                      <Body>
                        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
                        <Text>Topic{item.topicId}</Text>
                      </Body>
                    </Left>
                  </CardItem>
                  <CardItem cardBody>
                    <Image
                      style={{ height: 300, flex: 1 }}
                      source={{
                        uri:
                          "http://www.pixedelic.com/themes/geode/demo/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2014/04/placeholder4.png"
                      }}
                    />
                  </CardItem>
                </Card>
              )}
            />
          </View>
        </Content>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flex: 1, position: "absolute", bottom: 50, left: 0, right: 0, justifyContent: 'space-between', padding: 15 }}>
        <Button iconLeft onPress={() => this._deckSwiper._root.swipeLeft()}>
          <Text>Swipe Left</Text>
        </Button>
        <Button iconRight onPress={() => this._deckSwiper._root.swipeRight()}>
          <Text>Swipe Right</Text>
        </Button>
      </View>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```